# laravel id value changed after adding a nested loop

Tags: php, foreach, eloquent, laravel-8, nested-loops

I used the following code to display the role of the user
however, when I want to edit or delete it leads me to the deleted ids number 2/3 it return the same thing even when I change the for else with `foreach` `Attempt to read property "id" on null (View: C:\laravel\gauto\resources\views\dashboard\user\edit.blade.php)!`
when I delete the nested `foreach` loop everything back to normal
thank you in advance

```
                            @forelse($users as $item)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if($item->email_verified_at)
                                            {{ "verified" }}
                                        @else
                                            {{ "not verified" }}
                                        @endif
                                    </td>
                                    <td>    
                                        @foreach($item->roles as $item)
                                            {{ $item['name'] }} 
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{ route('user.edit', $item->id) }}">Edit</a>
                                        <form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $item->id) }}" method="POST">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('delete')
                                            <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ??')" type="submit">Delete</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @empty
                                <tr>
                                    blank data
                                </tr>
                            @endforelse
```

Comment: `@foreach($item->roles as $item)` - stop overwriting your $item variable ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users are also saved in $item and in the loop you are allocating $item a different value every time.

Try changing the code to

```
<td>    
      @foreach($item->roles as $role)
           {{ $role['name'] }} 
      @endforeach
</td>
```

Comment: maybe you can help me with this im new to blade in laravel i have this issue  @if($role['name'] == user)<a href="#">profile</a>@endif i want to display a certain link if the role is user it gives me  a Undefined constant "user"

Comment: @if($role['name'] == "user")<a href="#">profile</a>@endif